# Different sum between dataframe column and its array in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The dataframe has only one column "age" and it has 140 million rows.
For example, `df.agg(sum("age"))` and `df.rdd.map(x=>x(0).toString.toFloat).sum` get different values. There is almost three times the difference between them.

Comment: why are you doing`x(0).toString.toFloat`? and which one is bigger and lesser?

Comment: Cause the age is string type. The 'df.agg(sum("age"))' is larger and it is right.

Comment: so you are saying that rdd sum is wrong?

Comment: No, I do not cast the age to integer. I want to sum it as float, because I will sum other column of float type then. And I find that float type column sum is also different between the agg(sum()) and array sum. Really odd!

Comment: floating point arithmetic is not precise.

Comment: Maybe not this matter. The difference is too large. Correct is 3E9, but I only get 1E9 through array.sum.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465055/different-floating-point-precision-from-rdd-and-dataframe

Comment: If there is that large a difference, I agree that it shouldn't be due to floating point arithmetics (maybe if all values were very very small?). I guess the second example should have a `map` in it as well? Can you try using `x => x.getAs[Double](0)` to see if there is any difference?

Comment: Yes, I added the `map` in the question. The code has `rdd.map()`. I have tried it as change string to float in sparkSql and `x => x.getFloat(0)`. The bug also happens.

Comment: `var s=0.0 for(j<-0 until controlArray.length){s = s+ controlArray(j)}` and then I get the right sum. `reduce` `reduceLeft` cannot make it.

Comment: I suspect that there was some other difference which caused this error. I'm sure that `sum` and `reduce*` should work.

Comment: It is because the effective numbers of float type is not enough, so the sum in the end is smaller than actual result. When array.map(_.toDouble).sum ,the result is right.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the effective numbers of float type is not enough, so the sum in the end is smaller than actual result. When `array.map(_.toDouble).sum` ,the result is right.